# HTTP 400: The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared

Tags: http, jsp, jboss, struts, aws-fargate

Since I have deployed my struts based Java application over UAT environment using AWS Fargate,  AWS codepipeline and codebuild feature.

I'm getting HTTP 400 error on accessing a JSP page of my application. The url is like-

> `https://uat.xxx.org/xxx-partner/contract/suxxxriodxxxxxPairsAction.do?target=prepareSuxxxriodxxxxxPairs&contractIdSubPeriodId=416|837`

The same application on production, which is deployed as an ear over EC2 instance  works just fine.

Using [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-troubleshooting.html#http-400-issues) I tried troubleshooting HTTP 400, but it doesn't helps.
Because the request size is below 16k.

[image]

The codebuild for Fargate uses Wildfly 18.0 for deployment
whereas EC2 use JBoss 7.1.1 for deployment.

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aws has nothing to do with this error.
Wildfly 18.0 doesn't recognises pipe operator.

Also '|' (pipe) character is unsafe according to the RFC1738 specification of HTTP.

Hence [url encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/ref_urlencode.asp) must be used here to address the issue.